# Calculate two sums: $\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}$, $\sum_{i=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}) (\sqrt[4]{i}+\sqrt[4]{i+1})}$.

Tags: summation, closed-form

1. Calculate
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}$$

I've figured out that the answer is 9 -there is a pattern that I've figured out. I've created a code and solved it... but how could I do it more mathematically?

2. Calculate
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}) (\sqrt[4]{i}+\sqrt[4]{i+1})}$$

This one is a total mystery, any help would be appreciated. Sorry for bad formatting. And, I almost forgot; I'm new with computing sums, please provide clear and well explained answers.

Comment: The key is using `{}` and `\sqrt[4]{}` and the first one could probably be simplified by multiplying numerator end denominator by $\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}$.

Comment: hint: $1/(\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i})=\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}$

Comment: Thanks flawr for editing -appreciate it!

Comment: @Kurns Does my edited version accuralty show what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. The first sum can be easily handled observing that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}=\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}
$$ then by telescoping one gets

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}=\sqrt{n+1}-1.
> $$

The second sum can also be easily handled observing that
$$
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i})(\sqrt[4]{i+1}+\sqrt[4]{i})}=\sqrt[4]{i+1}-\sqrt[4]{i}
$$ then by telescoping one gets

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i})(\sqrt[4]{i+1}+\sqrt[4]{i})}=\sqrt[4]{n+1}-1.
> $$

Comment: Thanks mate! That one really helped.

Comment: @Kurns You are welcome.

Comment: But... By 'telescoping'? Care to explain a little further?

Comment: @Kurns [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) has a good explanation of a telescoping series.

Comment: You have for example $\sum_{i=1}^3(u_{i+1}-u_i)=(u_{2}-u_1)+(u_{3}-u_2)+(u_{4}-u_3)=u_{4}-u_1$ do you see it?

Comment: Okay, gotta look it up -by the way, there was a mistake in someone's editing, my second problem is in correct form now.

Answer (score 0):

Now, we have the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{9999} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}) \cdot\sqrt[4]{i}+\sqrt[4]{i+1}}$$
Whenever I see these kinds of problems, I always take the conjugate of the higher degree root first since that usually leads to a simpler expression. Thus, multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[4] i-\sqrt[4]{i+1}$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{9999} \frac{\sqrt[4] i-\sqrt[4]{i+1}}{(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}) \cdot\sqrt {i}-\sqrt {i+1}}$$
Simplify the denominator:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{9999} \frac{\sqrt[4] i-\sqrt[4]{i+1}}{i-(i+1)}$$
Simplify the denominator:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{9999} \frac{\sqrt[4] i-\sqrt[4]{i+1}}{-1}$$
Divide the denominator into the numerator:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{9999} \sqrt[4]{i+1}-\sqrt[4]i$$
Now, telescope:
$$\sqrt[4]{9999+1}-\sqrt[4]1=\sqrt[4]{10000}-\sqrt[4]1=10-1=9$$